# Validação de usuário e senha em Pop Up Modal usando MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal

Meu problema é o seguinte. Tenho um pop modal de login, conforme a imagem abaixo. Que quando o usuário digita seu login e senha e clica no botão login, ele chama meu `controller` Autentica. Segue o código do meu `controller`.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Autentica(string login_username, string login_password)
    {
        TSF_USUARIOS usuario = usuarioDAo.BuscaPorLoginSenha(login_username, login_password);

        if(usuario!=null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("login.invalido", "Usuário ou senha inválida.");
            return View();//Ainda procurando solução.
        }
    }
```

[image: Pop Up Modal Login]

Se o usuário digitar as informações corretas vai ser direcionado para tela inicial, até aí tudo ok. Porém se ele digitar as informações erradas, eu preciso informar uma mensagem para ele nesse Modal, aí que está meu problema, esse modal é aberto quando o usuário clica em um botão no menu. Se eu der um return view();, o popup é fechado. Estou usando o bootstrap.js para fazer a animação do modal. Existe alguma forma que eu consiga fazer no controller retorna o modal aberto e com a mensagem que eu adicionei na ModelState? Já procurei essa informação em vários fóruns porém em nenhum consegui resolver meu problema.

Segue meu `Modal`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                <img class="img-circle" id="img_logo" src="http://bootsnipp.com/img/logo.jpg">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="div-forms">
                <form id="login-form" action="/Usuario/Autentica" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="div-login-msg">
                            <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                            <span id="text-login-msg">Informe seu nome de usuário e senha.</span>
                        </div>
                        <input id="login_username" name="login_username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Login" required>
                        <input id="login_password" name="login_password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Senha" required>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> Salvar Senha
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Login" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button id="login_lost_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-link">Esqueceu a senha?</button>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Registrar", "Cadastro", "Usuario")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode fazer o envio com Ajax, já tentou fazer? Coloca o código do seu modal, aí vamos poder ver melhor seu problema.

Comment: @Ricardo, Segue o código do meu modal.

Answer (score 2):

Modifique seu método para o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Autentica(string login_username, string login_password)
{
    TSF_USUARIOS usuario = usuarioDAo.BuscaPorLoginSenha(login_username, login_password);

    if(usuario!=null)
    {
        return Json(new { resultado = "Ok" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet)
    }

    return Json(new { resultado = "NaoEncontrado" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

Modifique:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Login" />
```

Para:

```
<button id="botao-login">Login</button>
```

Implemente também na *View* o seguinte:

```
$("#botao-login").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("Autentica", "MeuController")",
        data: {
            login_username: $("#login-username").val();
            login_password: $("#login-password").val();
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado == "Ok") {
                window.location.replace("@Url.Action("Sucesso", "MeuController")");
            }

            // Exiba as mensagens de erro neste espaço. 
        }
    });
});
```

É importante dizer que esta não é a maneira boa de fazer isso. O ASP.NET MVC tem sua própria maneira de fazer login usando um framework de autenticação (preferencialmente o Identity). Apenas mostrei didaticamente como fazer, mas esta maneira não autentica seu usuário realmente.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: @WagnerBarbosaDoNascimento Se funcionou, [veja aqui quais são os próximos passos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!